# I have a dynamic menu and problem hide all menu after hover on submenu

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

my header code create DynamicMenu or main menu and DynamicMenu create DynamicSubMenu or sub menu.
problem: if hover on sub menu items hide main menu
My problem is that when I hover the submenu element the main menu disappears while it has to recognize that the main menu should not disappear.
**Header**

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <nav>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <DynamicMenu :data-prop="product_menues" name="test1"/>
        <DynamicMenu :data-prop="product_menues" name="test2"/>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </nav>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

**DynamicMenu**

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-menu
      open-on-hover
      offset-y
      left
      v-if=" menus && menus[0] && menus[0].url != null ? !isHidden : isHidden">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-list-item
          class="lg12 pl-6 pr-6"
          color="primary"
          link
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          <v-list-item-title
            plain
            color="primary"
            class="text-button"
            style="font-family: Vazir !important;"
            dark
          >
            {{ name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
      <v-list
      >
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(menu, index) in menus"
          :key="index"
          class="lg12 pa-0 ma-0"
          :to="menu.url"
          color="primary"
          link
        >

          <DynamicSubMenu :data-prop="menu.root_set" :name="menu.name"/>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

**DynamicSubMenu**

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-menu
      open-on-hover
      offset-x
      left>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-list-item
          class="lg12 pl-6 pr-6"
          color="primary"
          link
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          <v-list-item-title

            plain
            color="primary"
            class="text-button pl-0 pr-0 ma-0"
            style="font-family: Vazir !important;"
            dark


          >
            {{ name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
      <v-list

        v-if=" menus && menus[0] && menus[0].url != null ? !isHidden : isHidden"
      >

        <v-list-item
          v-for="(menu, index) in menus"
          :key="index"
          class="lg12 pl-6 pr-6"
          :to="menu.url"
          color="primary"
          link
        >
          <v-list-item-title

            class="text-button lg12"
            style="font-family: IRANYekan !important;"
            plain
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"

          >
            {{ menu.name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thus is pretty difficult to understand tbh.

Comment: i have problem in view manage. how i can manage hover submenu for hold parent menu inside self menu.

Comment: @mkh I think it would be very complicated to do so as the hover behavior is defined by the prop and is only for the menu itself. 
One solution would be to make the main menu CLICKABLE and the submenu on HOVER.

Comment: i need use hover no CLICKABLE.